# Double tap in IOS Simulator Not working

Tags: python, appium, appium-ios, python-appium

I am trying to `double tap` an element in IOS Simulator using appium but unable to do so.

```
Methods tried:

action.tap(x=xx, y=yy, count=1).release().perform()
```

2 times in a row,but it seems there is a 2 second gap which in real world would not be a double tap

```
element.click
```

same problem as above

```
action.press(x=xx, y=yy).wait(500).release().perform().press(x=0, y=0).wait(500).perform()
```

no result

```
action.tap(x=xx, y=yy, count=2).release().perform()
```

no result.

Is there any thing else i can try or any other method which works on `ios`.

Comment: @Domestus any inputs?????????

Comment: I call in a similar way  the first method you listed, its not as fast as double tap, but its less than one second delay `Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x: xx, y: yy, count: 2).perform` .tap dont need release, only press need it

Comment: @juhlila u call `tap` 2 times?on real device or simulator? i am on simulator and in logs it shows 2 seconds gap!!!

Comment: I use it on real devices, never tried on simulator

Comment: @juhlila can you try on simulator and see if it works for you....there 50 bounty on offer :)

Comment: try this method like: yourdriver.tap(2, elem, 400) ... i think this would work. this method is not action method.

Comment: @juhlila it worked.... post your suggestion as answer...i will reward it bounty

Comment: good to help @vks, i posted it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call it in a similar way the first method you listed, its not as fast as double tap, but its less than one second delay 
`Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x: xx, y: yy, count: 2).perform`

`.tap` dont need to use `release`, only `.press` need it

Answer (score 1):

You should do both of the press commands before calling `perform()`:

```
action.press(x=xx, y=yy).release().wait(500).press(x=xx, y=yy).release().perform()
```

Comment: I tried this and many other variants...somehow its not working on ios simulator :(